# Center Vertex of a StarEmbedding

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How is the center vertex of a StarEmbedding determined?  It may be the vertex with the maximum betweenness but the docs are silent on the details of the StarEmbedding layout algorithm.

Comment: Look at the options for [`"StarEmbedding"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/method/StarEmbedding.html). If the default (`Automatic`) is not what you want, use the option `"Center"`, e.g., `StarGraph[15, GraphLayout -> {"StarEmbedding", "Center" -> #}] & /@ {Automatic, 10}`